# Iptables rules block docker service

Tags: docker, networking, iptables

I have VPS server with installed VPN (ikev2/strongswan) directly to system (without Docker) and also i have docker that should expose some service to world.

As my VPN was configured properly using iptables, i found my docker service non accessible from world by ip:port ..

Here is my `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:isakmp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ipsec-nat-t
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  10.10.10.0/24        anywhere             policy match dir in pol ipsec proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.10.10.0/24        policy match dir out pol ipsec proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-USER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

How to open docker service using iptables?

thanks in advance

How i configure iptables:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
iptables -Z
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport  500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in  --proto esp -s 10.10.10.10/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir out --proto esp -d 10.10.10.10/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/24 -o eth0 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in -s 10.10.10.10/24 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

without `iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP` everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
Please install Docker after iptables setup commands as Docker install own iptables rules.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DOCKER_USER chain to put any VPN iptables rules, that way it won't interfere with Docker automatic iptables configurations that shoud''nt be played with manually.
See : [manage iptables firewall for docker](https://medium.com/swlh/manage-iptables-firewall-for-docker-kubernetes-daa5870aca4d)